# jquery.touchwipe.cycle slider NOT WORKING for WINDOWS PHONE TOUCH SWIPE

Tags: jquery, windows-phone

we have used jquery.touchwipe.cycle  JQuery in our site for image slider. Though the touch swipe works fine in iPhone, it does not work in windows phone (lumia 520 | windows 8)